Can I chant a mantra while on a walk?
Can I chant any Mantra while on a walk? Specifically Maha mrityunjay Mantra, can I chant it while I'm out on a walk in evening? Because it's not always possible for me to sit down in a place and use japa maala to chant, i want to remember my lord and chant the mantra whenever possible.
Will the god get angry if I don't wear a yellow clothing and sit down at one place to chant?
Please tell me if scriptures allow to chant mantra while walking.

Yes you can, walking, cycling, driving etc etc

@Just_Do_It reference?

Mantra needs initiation, so Guru will tell details. Nama japa can be done without any restrictions and does not require initiation

Your question Can I chant any Mantra while on a walk? Specifically Maha mrityunjay Mantra..............Please tell me if scriptures allow to chant mantra while walking.
The following sloka from Kulārnava Tantram [Ch-15, Sloka-108], answers your question whether to chant a mantra or not while walking:

उष्णीशी कञ्चुकी नग्नो मुक्तकेशो गणावृतः । 
अपवित्रोत्तरीयश्चाशुचिर्गच्छश्च नो जपेत्‌ ॥ १०८ ॥

One should not perform Japa with his turban on, with cloak, naked,
hair disheveled, surrounded by retinue, unclean upper cloth or while
impure or while walking.॥ 108 ॥

Beware-1: The sloka [108] says that never do mantra Japa while walking .

There is no restriction to recite anywhere Nama Japa such as "Govindā Govindā" and "Rāmā Rāmā" because you do this japa with Bakthi Bhāvanā(भक्ति भावना), so requires no initiation. This habit of nama japam will create stronger samskarās(संस्कार/Latent Impressions on subconscious mind) which is stored in Kārana Sarīra (कारण शरीर/Causal Body). When such samskarās grow stronger and stronger, even in our sleep unknowingly this japa will continue! That is power of habituation!
Bhagavān Krishna says in Bhagavath Geetha [8.5] about taking future birth that depends upon your thought at the time of death as given below:
अन्तकाले च मामेव स्मरन्मुक्त्वा कलेवरम् |
य: प्रयाति स मद्भावं याति नास्त्यत्र संशय: || ५ ||

anta-kāle cha mām eva smaran muktvā kalevaram
yaḥ prayāti sa mad-bhāvaṁ yāti nāstyatra sanśhayaḥ || 5 ||

Those who relinquish the body while remembering Me at the moment of
death will come to Me. There is certainly no doubt about this.

If one thinks about a bird at the time of death, then he will assume a bird form in the forthcoming birth [Refer my Quora Post on Jada Bharatha(जडभरत)]. If you utter ‘Govinda’ at the moment of death, you will reach the Padāravinda(पदारविन्द/Lotus Feet) of Lod Krishna! At the moment of dying, out thoughts will be totally out of our control and in chaos, however the habituation of the Nama Japa, such as "Govinda Govinda" will come for our rescue!

I would like to know, Did you take Mantra Dīksha(मन्त्र दीक्षा/Initiation) from a competent Guru(सिद्ध गुरु/the one who has perfected/acquired already the Mantra Siddhi for that mantra)? A mantra properly acquired through initiation from a Guru should never be chanted while walking or standing on streets.
I) Rig Veda [7.59.12] describes Rudra [fierce form of Shiva] who grants moksha and below verse became popularly known as Mahā Mrityunjaya mantra as follows:

त्र्यम्बकं यजामहे सुगन्धिं पुष्टिवर्धनम् ।
उर्वारुकमिव बन्धनान्मृत्योर्मुक्षीय माऽमृतात् ॥ १२ ॥

oṃ tryàmbakaṃ yajāmahe sugándhiṃ puṣṭi-várdhanam ।
urvārukám iva bándhanān mṛtyór mukṣīya mā́ 'mṛ́tāt ॥ 12 ॥

We worship Three-Eyed lord, whose fame is fragrant, the augmenter of  
increase; may I be liberated from death, and, like the ripe cucumber
from its stalk, but not unto immortality.

— Rig Veda: 7.59.12


II) According to Sāradātilaka Tantram (शारदातिलक तन्त्रं/சாரதாதிலக தந்திரம்) [Chapter-18], Shiva (Mrityunjaya Mahādeva) trayaksharī (त्रयक्षरी/Three Syllable) Moola Mantra is given below:
ॐ जूं सः॥
Om jūm saha॥

1. Who is Rishi(ऋषि/Seer/मंत्र द्रष्टा/Who discovered Mantra) : Kahola (कहोल ऋषि).
2. What is Chandas(छन्दस्/Metrical Structure of Mantra): Gayatrī Chanda(गायत्री छन्द).
3. Who is Devatha(देवता): Mrityunjaya Devata (मृत्युञ्जय देवता)

Dyāna Slokam (ध्यान श्लोकम्) of Mrityunjaya Devata (मृत्युञ्जय देवता):

    ॐ चन्द्रार्कार्ग्निविलोचनं स्मितमुखं पद्मद्वयान्तः स्थितं
    मुद्रापाशमृगाक्षसूत्रविलसत्पाणिं हिमांशुप्रभम्।
    कोटीरेन्दुगलत्सुधाप्लुततनुं हारादिभूषोज्ज्वलं
    कान्त्या विश्वविमोहनं पशुपतिं मृत्युञ्जयं भावयेत्॥

Meaning of Dyāna Slokam:
    He has a smiling face. He is seated on a lotus and another lotus is above him. 
    His three eyes the moon, the sun and the fire. He is of effulgence of the moon.
    He has Jnāna-gesture, a noose, a deer and rosary of Aksa (अक्ष) beads. 
    The nectar flowing from the moon in his mated hair bathes his body.
    He is wearing garlands and other gems. His beauty charms the universe. 
    He is lord of the creatures and the conqueror of death.

The Purashcharana (पुरश्चरण) for Tantra Upāsana (तन्त्र उपासना) of Mrityunjaya Devatha (मृत्युञ्जय देवता) 
consists of only the following two angas(अङ्ग/Parts):
    i) Japa (जप): With concentrated mind, perform three lakh (3,00,000) moola mantra Japa.
    ii) Havana(हवन): Throw 30,000 Āhutis (आहुति/oblation) of 
                     Pāyasa (पायस/Hindi: Kheer-खीर/பாயாசம்) and Rice with
                     Ghrta(घृत/Ghee/घी) by uttering mantra 
                     ॐ जूं सः स्वाहा in the fire of Havana Kunda.
                     (Or)
                     Throw 30,000 Āhutis (आहुति/oblation) of Gurucha 
                     samidha (गुरुच समिधा/படர் கொடி சமிதி) smeared with 
                     Milk and Ghrta(घृत/Ghee) by uttering mantra
                     ॐ जूं सः स्वाहा in the fire of Havana Kunda.

    Note: Gurucha samidha (गुरुच समिधा) means twigs of self-rooted creepers on trees.
          Refer appendix for image of Gurucha samidha.

III) According to Mantra Mahodadi (मन्त्र महोदधि) [Chapter-16], Shiva (Mrityunjaya Mahādeva) panchasatāksharī (पञ्चाशताक्षरी/Fifty Syllable) Moola Mantra is given below:
ॐ हौं ॐ जूं सः भूर्भुवः स्वः त्र्यम्बकं यजामहे सुगन्धिं पुष्टिवर्धनम् उर्वारुकमिव बन्धनान्मृ त्योर्मुक्षीय मामृतात् भूर्भुवः स्वरों जूं सः हौं ॐ॥

1. Who is Rishi(ऋषि/Seer/मंत्र द्रष्टा/Who discovered Mantra): Vāmadevakaholavāshistā(वामदेवकहोलवासिष्टा ऋषि).
2. What is Chandas(छन्दस्/Metrical Structure of Mantra): Panktirgāyatraiyanushtup Chanda(पङ्क्तिर्गायत्रयनुष्टुप् छन्द).
3. Who is Devatha(देवता): SadāshivaMahāmrityunjayaRudra (सदाशिवमहामृत्युञ्जयरुद्र)

Dyāna Slokam (ध्यान श्लोकम्) of Mrityunjaya Devata (मृत्युञ्जय देवता):

    ॐ हस्ताम्भोजयुगस्थकुम्भयुगलादुद्धृत्य तोयं शिरः
    सिञ्चन्तं करयोर्युगेन दधतं स्वांके सकुम्भौ करौ।
    अक्षस्रङ्मृगहस्तमम्बुजगतं मूर्द्धस्थचन्द्रसस्रवत्
    पोयूषोऽत्रवतनुं भजे सगिरिजं मृत्युञ्जयं त्रयम्बकम्॥

Meaning of Dyāna Slokam:
    I meditate upon the three-eyed Mrtyunjaya, accompanied by goddess Grijā. 
    His two hands holding water-pot are kept on his lap. The other two hands above 
    them hold two other water-pots from which water is being taken by another 
    pair of hands still above and being splashed over his head. 
    The remaining two hands holding mrga and rosary.
    His body is drenched with nectar exuding from crescent moon held on his head.

The Purashcharana (पुरश्चरण) for Tantra Upāsana (तन्त्र उपासना) of 
Mrityunjaya Devatha (मृत्युञ्जय देवता) consists of only the following two angas(अङ्ग/Parts):
    i) Japa (जप): With focused mind, perform one lakh (1,00,000) moola mantra Japa, 
                  showing Musti, Sāranga, Sakti, Linga and Panchmukha mudras. 
       Note: All the five mudras are shown in the figure immediately below Yantras.
    ii) Havana(हवन): One tenth of the number of Japa, i.e by throwing 
                     10,000 Āhutis (आहुति/oblation) by uttering mantra
                     ॐ हौं ॐ जूं सः भूर्भुवः स्वः त्र्यम्बकं यजामहे सुगन्धिं पुष्टिवर्धनम्
                     उर्वारुकमिव बन्धनान्मृ त्योर्मुक्षीय मामृतात् भूर्भुवः स्वरों जूं सः हौं ॐ स्वाहा 
                     in the fire of Havana Kunda. Havana should be 
                     preformed with ten dravya (द्रव्य/Substances) which are: 
                     (1) Bilva fruit, (2) Tile/तिल/Sesame, (3) Khīra/खीरा/Cucumber,
                     (4) Ghrta/घृत/Ghee, (5) Milk, (6) Curd, (7) Dūrvā/दूर्वा/Grass,
                     (8) Samidha of Vata tree (वट वृक्ष/Banyan tree/ஆல மரம்), 
                     (9) Samidha of Palāsa tree (पलाश वृक्ष) and
                     (10) Samidha of Khadirā tree (खदिर वृक्ष/கதிர மரம்). 
                     The three samidha (समिधा/Twigs) should be soaked in 
                     Trimadhura (त्रिमधुर) which are Ghrta, Honey and Sugar 
                     before throwing into fire.

                     Note: To identify twigs of trees, refer figure at the bottom.

IV) According to Sri Kulārnava Tantram (श्रीकुलार्णव तन्त्रम्) that asserts about mantra dīksha from a Guru as given below:

उपासनाशतेनापि याम् विना नैव सिद्यति ।
ताम् दीक्षामाश्रयेद् यत्नात् श्रीगुरोर्म सिद्धये ॥ १४.७७ ॥

That dīksha without which there is no Mantra Siddhi (मन्त्रसिद्धि/Fulfillment) 
even with hundred Upāsanās, should be obtained
from a competent Guru [सिद्ध गुरु], the one who has perfected/acquired
already the Mantra Siddhi for that mantra, for the success of the
mantra. ॥ 14.88 ॥

अनकेकोटिमन्त्राणि चित्ताकुलकराणि च ।
मन्त्रं गुरुकृपाप्राप्तमेकं स्यात् सर्वसिद्धिदम् ॥ १५.१९ ॥

Innumerable are mantras; they but distract the mind. Only that mantra
which is received through the Grace of the Guru gives all fulfilment.॥ 15.19॥


Beware-2: According to Sri Kulārnava Tantram (श्रीकुलार्णव तन्त्रम्), you need initiation (Mantra Dīksha/मन्त्र दीक्षा) in order to carry out Mrityunjaya mantra japa.
V) The following sloka from Kulārnava Tantram [Ch-15, Sloka-21], says about which are the mantras recitable (without repetition nor japa carried out for devata siddhi) with bakthi bhāvana:

पुस्तके लिखितान्मन्तान् विलोक्य प्रजपन्ति ये ।
ब्रह्महत्यासम् तेषां पतकम् व्याधिदुःखदम् ॥ १५.२१ ॥

Those who seeing Mantras written in books, practice Japa of
them,commit a sin tantamount to brahmahatti [brahmanicide] resulting
in disease and misery.


Beware-3: This implies that never do Japa of uninitiated Mantra. So, Kulārnava Tantram [Ch-15, Sloka-21] permits to chant Ashtottara Sata Namāvali, Sahasra Namāvali, Kavacha, Bhajan, Chālisa, Nama Japa, and Gāyatri mantra but never as Tantric Japa Upāsana.

Conclusion:
According to Kulārnava Tantram [14.88, 15.19], Mantra(aka Moola Mantra) should be acquired through a competent Guru and subsequently Tantra Sadhana is carried out with Purascharana including Nyāsa in order to attain Mantra Siddhi or Devatha Vasyam.

Therefore, you need initiation (Mantra Dīksha/मन्त्र दीक्षा) in order to carry out Mrityunjaya mantra japa.
Beware-4: A mantra properly acquired through initiation from a Guru should never be chanted while walking or standing on streets.
Beware-5: Of course, you can always recite the Dyāna Sloka associated Moola mantra anywhere.

However, Ashtottara Sata Namāvali, Sahasra Namāvali, Kavacha, Bhajan, Chālisa, Nama Japa, and Gāyatri mantra for various Devathas are chanted in houses and temples particularly in Tamil Nadu only with Bakthi Bhāvanā(भक्ति भावना), but with no initiation. The purpose of worship through chanting is not for Mantra Siddhi (मन्त्र सिद्धि) because these are not Moola Mantras. Therefore these slokas and mantras (uninitiated) can be chanted while walking or anywhere.

Appendix:
The Mamopātta Sankalpa Mantra (ममोपात्त सङ्कल्प मन्त्र/மமோபாத்த சங்கல்ப மந்திரம்) for Mrityunjaya Devata Japa is as follows:
ममोपात्त समस्त दुरितक्षय द्वारा श्रीपरमॆश्वर प्रीत्यर्थं
मृत्युञ्जय देवता महा मन्त्र जपम् अहम् करिष्ये॥
Or Vaisnava followers:
ममोपात्त समस्त दुरितक्षय द्वारा श्रीमन्नारायण प्रीत्यर्थं
मृत्युञ्जय देवता महा मन्त्र जपम् अहम् करिष्ये॥

Mamopātta samastha durithakshaya dwāra Sri Parameshwara preethyartham
Mrityunjaya Devatā mahā mantra japam aham karishye॥
Or Vaisnava followers:
Mamopātta samastha durithakshaya dwāra Srimannārāyana preethyartham
Mrityunjaya Devatā mahā mantra japam aham karishye॥

-Sarvajana Sarva Devata Puja Paddhati, Chapter-1.





Good Luck!

Yes, you can do. However, a few Mantras need you to satisfy some specific purifications and conditions. So, I suggest chanting the name of the Lord you love instead because chanting names has no such rules and regulations.
Few references:

Does nAma-japa also require dikshA (initiation)?

Is any god name eligible for nama japa?


